# Animation on canvas two loops at once

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Global for the main game loop

```
var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame  ||  
                    window.oRequestAnimationFrame   || 
                    function(callback) {
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
                    };
```

Below you can see that this function should start an animation. What it does however it speeds through the animation without enough time to see it. This I think is because the main game loop overrides it. I Do not know how to solve this?

```
function DrawSpawnAnimation() {


        anim();
    }

     function anim() {

    //alert(explodeY);

            ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, ExplodeFrame * 100, 2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);

          if(ExplodeFrame == 5)
         {
         ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, 6, 2851,100,106,(Player.x - 50) + 10,(Player.y - 50) + 10,100,100);

         }
          else if(ExplodeFrame == 6)
         {
         ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, 106,  2851,100,106,(Player.x - 50) + 10,(Player.y - 50) + 10,100,100);

         }
         else if(ExplodeFrame == 7)
         {
         ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, 206,  2851,100,106,(Player.x - 50) + 10,(Player.y - 50) + 10,100,100);

         }
          else if(ExplodeFrame == 8)
         {
         ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, 306,  2851,100,106,(Player.x - 50) + 10,(Player.y - 50) + 10,100,100);

         }
           else if(ExplodeFrame == 9)
         {
         ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, 406,  2851,100,106,(Player.x - 50) + 10,(Player.y - 50) + 10,100,100);

         }



            if (ExplodeFrame < 9) {     
                ExplodeFrame++;
                 setTimeout(anim, 1000 / 15);

            } 

        else
        {
        Death = false;
        ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, 506,  2851,100,106,(Player.x - 50) + 10,(Player.y - 50) + 10,100,100);
        ExplodeFrame = 0;
        }

        //alert("hi");
        }
```

In this function if the player is dead it calls the explode animation.

```
function Loop(){




if (isPlaying == true)
{
//document.addEventListener('click', pauseClicked ,false); //WARNING REMOVE THIS WHEN YOU CLICK MENU OR EXIT LEVEL IN ANYWAY


Platforms = [];
Lavas = [];
Flags = [];
Teleporters = [];

Prepare();




if(level == 1)
{

Level1();
}

else if(level == 2)
{
Level2();
}

else if (level ==3)
{
Level3();
}

else if (level == 4)
{
Level4();
}

else if (level ==5)
{
Level5();
}

else if (level ==6)
{
Level6();
}

else if (level ==7)
{
Level7();
}

else if (level ==8)
{
Level8();
}

else if (level ==9)
{
Level9();
}

else if (level ==10)
{
Level10();
}

else if (level ==11)
{
Level11();
}




else
{

stopLoop();
}


 if(ElevatorOn == true)
  {
   drawElevators();

  }

  if(LavaElevatorOn == true)
  {
    drawLavaElevators();
  }

  if(TeleportersOn == true)
  {
  drawTeleporters();

  }

  movePlayer();  
checkCol();
if(Death == false)
{
drawPlayer();
}

drawGUI();


if(Death ==true)
{

DrawSpawnAnimation();
requestAnimFrame(Loop);

}

else
{
requestAnimFrame(Loop); //this calls it again
}


}
}
```

Comment: I did as you said, but nothing happened, it did the same thing. I don't understand as it seem the first loop overrides the other one because it is faster?

Comment: The setTimeout is asynchronous meaning that when you request a setTimeout the code inside the timeout will be run after the specified timeout, but the code after the timeout gets to run immediately (no timeout). Therefore there is no delay for any code that is after setTimeout and your elevator animation gets to keep running uninterrupted.  No overriding going on!  The RAF keeps your elevator moving and the setTimeout animates your explosion--no interference between the two processes.   No overlaps, No delays!

Comment: One thing I do see is that you're doing clipping to get each sprite out of your spritesheet. This might cause a glitchy delay just because that clipping process takes a while.  Instead try to cut the spritesheet into separate sprite images.  Do that once before you let the user start playing.  If you need help with this clipping let me know...I'd be glad to help ;)

Comment: Thanks, Because It was glitchy I turned it around a little so now when the player dies the elevators go backwards and the glitchy effect makes it look like its going back in time so Im gunna stick with it, added sound effects and all. Thanks though its starting to look pretty cool :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to look at the animation frame problem right now, but there are two other things you should definitely do:

1. Format and indent your code. It's not very consistent. There are many JavaScript beautifiers you can find with a search for "javascript beautifier". Pick one and run your code through it, and then as you make future changes keep the formatting consistent—or run it through the beautifier again.
2. Simplify, simplify, simplify! For example, consider this code (reformatted here):

```js
if( level == 1 ) {
    Level1();
} else if( level == 2 ) {
    Level2();
} else if( level == 3 ) {
    Level3();
} else if( level == 4 ) {
    Level4();
} else if( level == 5 ) {
    Level5();
} else if( level == 6 ) {
    Level6();
} else if( level == 7 ) {
    Level7();
} else if( level == 8 ) {
    Level8();
} else if( level == 9 ) {
    Level9();
} else if( level == 10 ) {
    Level10();
} else if( level == 11 ) {
    Level11();
} else {
    alert( "Game over - Still in development - Wayne Daly 2013" );
    stopLoop();
}
```

You can replace all that code with:

```js
var levelFun = levelFunctions[level];
if( levelFun ) {
    levelFun();
} else {
    alert( "Game over - Still in development - Wayne Daly 2013" );
    stopLoop();
}
```

and then where you have all the `Level()`, `Level2()`, etc. functions defined, replace them all with:

```js
var levelFunctions = [
    null,  // there is no level 0
    function() {
        // level 1 function
    },
    function() {
        // level 2 function
    },
    ...
];
```

You can also simplify that long list of `if(ExplodeFrame == N)` tests to all use a common bit of code. Just calculate the second parameter to `ctxAnimation.drawImage()` with `( ExplodeFrame - 5 ) * 100 + 6` instead of all the `if` tests and hard coded values.

Comment: Thank you, its only my second year programming, and 4th week into actually making anything move on screen. I'm trying to cram everyone at once, must take some time out soon and improve my code, and maybe draw out idea's before trying to program everything :)